# Disable then enable button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i need a button to get disabled after its clicked and then after few seconds it should become enabled again. I added a class button-disabled since i want to use it couple of times on the same page. Here is what i tried

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-disabled', function (){
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                }, 3500);
                }); 


<button type="button" id="buttonSettings" class="btn btn-success button-disabled">Sacuvaj</button>
```

I looked up similar questions on the site, but none of those help because everytime buttons does get disabled after click but it never gets enabled again. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setTimeout` is always executed in the global scope, as it's really `window.setTimeout` (or more accurately `WindowTimers`), so inside the callback `this` will be the window, not the element.

You have to store a reference to the element

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-disabled', function (){

      var element = $(this);

      element.prop('disabled', true);

      setTimeout(function() {

           console.log(this); // gives "window"

           element.prop('disabled', false);

      }, 3500);
});
```

As a sidenote, newer browsers accepts additional arguments in `setTimeout` so you could also do

```
setTimeout(function(element) {
    $(element).prop('disabled', false);
}, 3500, this);
```

or using `bind()`

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
}.bind(this), 3500);
```

Comment: As far as I know your last paragraph is incorrect -- although arguments can be passed to the callback this way, `this` cannot be bound by passing it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - just a typo, was supposed to use the argument instead.

Comment: So what would passing `this` to `setTimeout()` achieve, then? :)

Comment: It's just another way to lock in the value of `this` by passing it instead of using a variable. Of course `bind` could be used as well, but I don't really like that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of `this` & use the instance to remove disable. Can try something like below.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.button-disabled', function (){
     var self = $(this);
     $(this).prop('disabled', true);
     setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).removeAttr('disabled');
     }, 3500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="buttonSettings" class="btn btn-success button-disabled">Sacuvaj</button>
```